# What is the use of "-j8" argument passed to make

Tags: makefile

What is the difference between

```
$ make all
```

and,

```
$ make all -j8
```

Answer (score 1):

From `man make`

> -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
>   Specifies  the  number of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more than one -j option, the last one is
>   effective.  If the -j option is given without
>   an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously.